# Why jobs table are empty when dispatching a job in Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue

I'm using laravel  6

I've been struggling all the day to figure out why jobs table never get populated when I dispatch a job

When I hit this artisan command `php artisan queue:work`

I get the following

```
[2020-04-08 11:37:04][12] Processing: App\Jobs\SendEmail
[2020-04-08 11:37:05][12] Processed:  App\Jobs\SendEmail
[2020-04-08 11:37:05][13] Processing: App\Mail\ActivationEmail
[2020-04-08 11:37:06][13] Processed:  App\Mail\ActivationEmail
```

Email get sent successfuly..

I changed some configurations in **config.php**

```
 'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'database'),
```

as well as **.env**

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

**failed_jobs** and **jobs** tables are migrated..

jobs table always empty...

why this is happening ?

Comment: because it is processed...

Answer (score 3):

Because jobs processed **successfully** and run **immediately**,

if you set **delay** you can see it in the jobs table or if you have an **exception** while running `jobs`, you can see it in the `failed_jobs` table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're queueing new jobs in code, have you run `php artisan config:clear`? It's possible that your config settings have been cached; changing the env file if they are won't have any effect until you've cleared the config cache.